# Input for list in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple list in a VueJS template :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>This is the list of groups :</h3>
    <ul>
      <div v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
        <li>
          <strong>{{ group.id }}</strong> : <span>{{ group.name }}</span>
          <button @click="deleteGroup(group.id)">Delete</button>
          <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="update name">
          <button @click="updateGroup(group.id)">Update</button>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

The thing is, in my rendered page, when I type in something in the input, it is typed in every  input of the list (see image below).

[image]

How can I avoid that behaviour ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Obviously all your inputs bind (`v-model`) to the same variable `name`, by changing one input will change `name`, which leads to affect all of your inputs, it's expected.

Comment: That's it. How could I change my template in order not to do that ? I have no idea since I'm kinda new in VueJS

Comment: You kinda need each binding variable for each input (instead of one `name` variable for all). Each element of `groups` need to hold a `model` for your corresponding input. Try running the code snippet of my answer below.

Comment: I've had a look at it and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your inputs bind `(v-model)` to the same variable `name`, by changing one input will change `name`, which will lead to affect all of your inputs, it's expected.

---

**Original answer verions:**
But as I understand what you want, here's the code to get what you desired (by changing `v-model="name"` to `v-model="group.edittingName"`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    groups: [
        { id: 1, name: 'groupname1', edittingName: '' },
        { id: 2, name: 'groupname2', edittingName: '' },
        { id: 3, name: 'groupname3', edittingName: '' },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    deleteGroup(id) {
      this.groups = this.groups.filter(gr => gr.id !== id)
    },
    updateGroup(id) {
      const targetInput = this.groups.find(x => x.id === id)
      targetInput.name = targetInput.edittingName
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>This is the list of groups :</h3>
  <ul>
    <div v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
      <li>
        <strong>{{ group.id }}</strong> : <span>{{ group.name }}</span>
        <button @click="deleteGroup(group.id)">Delete</button>
        <input v-model="group.edittingName" type="text" placeholder="update name">
        <button @click="updateGroup(group.id)">Update</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Update 1:** To get the models from the server only contain `id` and `name`, to not modify that model structure, and to make the title `group.name` change its value only after a button click, here is a workaround. But this one uses **one way binding** through events instead of two way binding v-model though. But I think whether update constantly or not is the difference between "1wb" and "2wb".

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    groups: [
        { id: 1, name: 'groupname1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'groupname2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'groupname3' },
    ],
    curEditInput: null
  },
  methods: {
    deleteGroup(id) {
      this.groups = this.groups.filter(gr => gr.id !== id)
    },
    updateGroup(id) {
      const toUpdate = this.groups.find(gr => gr.id === id)
      toUpdate.name = this.curEditInput.value
    },
    changeFocus(e) {
      this.curEditInput = e.target
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>This is the list of groups :</h3>
  <ul>
    <div v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
      <li>
        <strong>{{ group.id }}</strong> : <span>{{ group.name }}</span>
        <button @click="deleteGroup(group.id)">Delete</button>
        <input @focus="changeFocus" type="text" placeholder="update name">
        <button @click="updateGroup(group.id)">Update</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Update 2:** As the OP had a desire to use the two-way binding v-model approach and also make the label to only update after complete editing on the `<input>`. Now I find out that `v-model` has a thing called [`modifier .lazy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy), The difference between the Update 2 (v-model) approach vs Update 1 (event) approach is in the v-model approach, the label will update right away as you lost focus the input, **whether you click the Update button or not**, or after pressing the Enter, etc. On the other hand, in the Update 1 (event) approach, the label will **only update when you click the corresponding Update button**. And I don't know, maybe this one's what he wants, maybe that one suits better.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    groups: [
        { id: 1, name: '' },
        { id: 2, name: '' },
        { id: 3, name: '' },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    deleteGroup(id) {
      this.groups = this.groups.filter(gr => gr.id !== id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>This is the list of groups :</h3>
  <ul>
    <div v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
      <li>
        <strong>{{ group.id }}</strong> : <span>{{ group.name }}</span>
        <button @click="deleteGroup(group.id)">Delete</button>
        <input v-model.lazy="group.name" placeholder="update name">
        <button>Update</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**An easy way thinking about .lazy and v-model:**

```html
<input v-model="nameModel">
will transpile to
<input :value="nameModel" @input="nameModel = $event.target.value">

whereas
<input v-model.lazy="nameModel">
will be equivalent to
<input :value="nameModel @change="nameModel = $event.target.value">
```

Comment: Indeed it works. The thing is I'm using VueJS for the frontend and my models come from the backend that is done in Django (with a graphql API on top of it, which is accessed with Apollo). With your solution, I have to add an extra field on my model(s) to achieve what I want ? I thought there would be an option or something with the v-for or to do in the v-for directly.

Comment: @lbris I edited the answer accordingly to not modify the structure of `groups`, but it uses `event` instead of `v-model`, but still looks simple btw. Is it ok?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot ! However I feel like it is haggling doing this. But if it is the only way to achieve what I want... Thanks :)

Comment: @lbris I think that's how much current VueJS API provides us. If there's a better way, I will always be eager to learn.

Comment: Same for me. If (one day) I find a more direct solution to this, I'll post it here.

Comment: @lbris Hey, I've found out that there's a thing called [v-model lazy modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy), maybe you should give it a look. Even though I don't think its behavior is better than the event approach I gave earlier. I updated the answer accordingly as well, try the snippet I put above.

Comment: Hey ! This is nice since it only writes in 1 input field (until you lose focus or press the update button). I think there is no way to do an update list like that, in a proper way with VueJS, I mean without playing with events and so on. I don't know if there is a point to do such an updatable list either. I'd better do a button that opens a view for the desired group and that's all ^^. Thank you for the update anyway, this is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

change the v-model  binding from name to `group.temporaryName` to separate each input data binding.

groups data structure  looks like this

```js
  groups: [
     { id: 1,  name: '', temporaryName: '' },
     { id: 2,  name: '', temporaryName: '' },
     { id: 3,  name: '', temporaryName: '' }
    ]
```